# Append a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list

How can I append a dictionary like the following in Python?

```
list1 = {'value1':1}
list2 = {'value2':2}

list1.append(list2)
```

When appending:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How can I join both list then?

Comment: It's not a list it's a dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are dictionaries, not lists.

Try `list1.update(list2)`

The semantics of update and append are different, because the underlying data structures are different. Values for existing keys in the dictionary will be overwritten by their values in the argument dictionary.

The section of the Python Tutorial on [Data Structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) goes through this and a whole lot more.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains everything... Thanks :P

Comment: @Jerry are you in actual fact trying to update a dictionary - or were you expecting something else?

Comment: @JonClements I was looking for that answer, yeah. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though these are dictionaries and not lists, like Owen said, for *appending* to a dictionary use update() function.

Example:

```
list1 = {'value1': 1}
list2 = {'value2': 2}
list1.update(list2)
```

Otherwise, if you need appending to lists, simply use **append**:

```
l = range(10)
l.append(range(10, 19))
```

Notice that the last example appends a **list** and not **10 numbers**, so in this case its length would be 11.

Comment: When you're talking about `dict`s, I wouldn't use the word *append* at all- it just doesn't describe the operation that's being done, and it risks creating the same kind of confusion that led the OP to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: This is why I used italic in _appending_. Look above.